# JavaScript regex not working for PHP

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have a javascript regex

```
   Value.match(/[A-Za-z0-9\-\,\.\(\)/]/)
```

This gives me  1 if a string contains alphabets, numbers, hyphen, comma, dot or braces; if any other character is found it gives 0.

When I apply same regex in PHP it is not working. Why?

Comment: no code provided along with the powerful description of `is not working`...  do you really expect solid answers??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape characters inside `[]` so you can try this `/[A-Za-z0-9,.()]/` or even this one `/[\w,.()]/` but if you want to check that the string *contains only* those characters that regex won't do, try:

```
/^[\w,.()]+$/
```

I noticed that you also have `/`. Is that intentional or a mistake, because you don't mention it in the question...

Comment: In javascript `/` is used to mark regexps while you have to put the regex into a string in php. so this might be the main problem. but your answer has a good point. +1

Comment: ^ Right, that could be the problem too. We need to see php code.

Comment: Thank you for your help !! Its working !!  :-) !! I used \/ for checking / !! Need two more help !! One it checks a string containing only a word what if it is a sentence with spaces ex "there is my error". Two can you guide me to a resource link where i can learn regex in php  !! Thank you once again

Comment: Regex are pretty much the same across languages. I think the best resource is http://www.regular-expressions.info/. It's language agnostic but it it'll tell you if something differs in other languages.

Comment: Thanks really appreciate you help !!  :-) !! And your link was awesome !!